# Visual Studio 2012 Windows kernel debugging - can't provision VM target

Tags: windows, debugging, visual-studio-2012, kernel, virtualbox

- *Host:*   Visual Studio 2012, Windows 8 Host, WDK8
- *Target:* VirtualBox - Windows 7

When I try to add the target computer (Driver -> Test -> Configure Computers) in Visual Studio (like at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439359%28v=vs.85%29.aspx ):

- I select "Provision Computer and choose debugger settings"
- I choose to use a Serial connection
- But the result is always "Could not find a host entry for *Name of VM*"

VS gives the same response if I try to connect through the network (I know kernel debugging from a Win8 host to a Win7 target isn't supported through the network).

I can't see a problem in the connection; connection without provision works after hitting Debug -> Break (otherwise, I hit a *Waiting to reconnect...* message).

Anyone get this working or has better idea on how to debug the Windows OS in VirtualBox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not choose the debugger option to provision the target, as the debugger docs state that "Provisioning is not supported for virtual machines." (See this page: [Provision a computer for driver deployment and testing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/hardware/dn745909).) This is most likely because provisioning requires network connectivity to the target, no matter how you choose to connect for the actual kernel debugging session.

As you've already observed, connection without provisioning works just fine, so you can just do that instead. Make sure you've properly attached the virtual serial port on the target to a host named pipe.

In any case, provisioning isn't strictly necessary to run the kernel debugger. It's just a convenience that automatically enables kernel debugging on the target, makes some other useful configuration changes, and installs a set of useful tools. You can see what provisioning does on this page: [What happens when you provision a computer?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows-drivers/develop/what_happens_when_you_provision_a_computer__wdk_8_1_)

Here is some general guidance on setting up kernel debugging of a VM: [Setting Up Kernel-Mode Debugging of a a Virtual Machine in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/hardware/jj200334)

Answer (score 0):

This link [Kernel-Mode Debugging in a VM using Visual Studio 2012](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/545835/Kernel-Mode-Debugging-in-a-VM-using-Visual-Studio)describes how to provision to virtual machine. You will need to configure network in a way that host and guest can ping each other. 
After that you need to update "hosts" on both computers(add ip and NetBIOS of guest to host "hosts" file and ip and NetBIOS of host to guest "hosts" file).